# Word cloud with weights represented in size and direction of relationship by colour in R

Tags: r, pca, word-cloud

I have done a PCA and I want to create a wordcloud that represents the weights and direction of relationship (positive or negative) of the different dimensions of the component of the PCA.
I have this code in R

```
pca_loadings$colorRC1 <- ifelse(pca_loadings[,1] >= 0, 'red', 'blue')
pca_loadings$absRC1 <- abs(pca_loadings[,1]) 
wordcloud::wordcloud(words = pca_loadings$V5, 
                     freq = pca_loadings$absRC1, scale = c(3,1), 
                     min.freq = 0.3, 
                     max.words = 20, 
                     ordered.colors = T, 
                     colors = pca_loadings$colorRC1, 
                     rot.per = 0)
```

it kind of works. `pca_loadings$V%` is where the name of each dimension is stored, `absRC1` is the absolute value of the weights for each dimension for component 1. I want the cutoff to be 0.3, so anything smaller is not included in the word cloud.

To make the colour vary depending on whether it is positive or negative I have created a variable called `colorRC1` which basically looks at the weights of each dimension, if the number is >0 it writes red in that row, if <0 it writes blue.

So far so good. However, because the minimum threshold is 0.3, whenever the wordcloud function gets to a row with an absolute value smaller than 0.3, it omits it but it does not skip the colour row, so then the `absRC1` column and the colour column dont match. basically in the output the size is fine, but because it does not skip a row in the colour column whenever a value is smaller than 0.3, the direction of the numbers (positive or negative) doesnt match the colour they are printed in.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: You could filter out / subset the data to exclude the rows with too-low values before you send it to wordcloud.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t have access to your `pca_loadings` table, so I’m creating
a `data.frame` that resembles the features necessary for this example.

```r
library(tidyverse) 
  
pca_loadings <- 
  data.frame(
    V5 = words[1:30],
    RC1 = rnorm(30)
  )
```

We can make the modifications for color and absolute values with
`dplyr::mutate()` and then filter out rows with values below `0.3` with `dplyr::filter()`.

```r
pca_loadings_mod <- 
  pca_loadings |> 
  mutate(colorRC1 = ifelse(RC1 >= 0, 'red', 'blue'),
         absRC1 = abs(RC1)) |> 
  filter(absRC1 >= .3)

wordcloud::wordcloud(words = pca_loadings_mod$V5, 
                     freq = pca_loadings_mod$absRC1, scale = c(3,1), 
                     max.words = 20, 
                     ordered.colors = TRUE, 
                     colors = pca_loadings_mod$colorRC1, 
                     rot.per = 0)
```

[image]

Comment: thank you, ill try it now but it should work.